# Hard drive wiping?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Erasing data before selling a computer](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer)
>   [How to wipe a USB hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/86694/how-to-wipe-a-usb-hard-drive)

Hi guys!

I have internal and external hard drives. I don't want to have to go through and delete each one manually. I don't have that kind of spare time. Do you know about some tested software or something?

thanks a lot.
I have windows 7.

Comment: Also http://superuser.com/questions/154643/program-to-wipe-hd/154645#154645

Answer (score 2):

- Bootable CD: `DBAN` (Darik's Boot And
  Nuke).
- Alternatively, a bootable
  Linux CD with the program '`wipe`'. 
  That one would be more complex to use
  though, as you are more familiar with Windows.

I assume that you don't want **any** of the data on those drives, **EVER** again.  If that is not the case, these are the wrong tools.

Comment: Also a simple `dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdX` works quiet well for deleting *everything* (including the partition table) on the drive. If you want it clean and nice afterwards you can use `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdX`.

Comment: Having used (or attempted to) your method, you will find it absurdly slow.  I would be surprised if you wiped a gig before the week was out.  /dev/random only uses real entropy.  You run out of entropy really fast.  /dev/urandom is better.  It will keep going at a moderate clip but drain all of your CPU generating cryptographic random numbers.  I suggest a combination of wiping and random numbers (which is what DBAN and wipe do), but if you are cleaning it against an unsophisticated attacker, dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<device> would work fine.  (/dev/null doesn't output anything, use /dev/zero)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to continue to be able to use these drives?

If not, a large hammer is the fastest solution.