# How to properly wipe a hard drive prior to resale?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, security

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Hard drive wiping?](https://superuser.com/questions/155264/hard-drive-wiping)
>   [Erasing data before selling a computer](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer)

I'm going to be selling a few old hard drives and was wondering what is the correct way to wipe these hard drives clean so that no information could be recovered from them..

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 10.

Answer (score 1):

[Download](http://www.dban.org/download) a Darik's Boot and Nuke .iso; it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. link doesn't seem to work though! I will try again later

Comment: the link is working greatly for me

Answer (score 0):

Copy a stream from /dev/zero or /dev/random to your harddrive using [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)).

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=1M
```

Where **if** is the stream you copy from, and **of** your harddrive you want to wipe off.

hda is primary master, hdb primary slave, hdc secondary master, sda is the first SCSI drive etc...

bs is the block size used.

To check that it really worked use:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | hexdump -C | head
```